# Тренажер T-SQL

Tags: sql-server

Есть ли сайты, на которых можно потренироваться составлять длинные запросы?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, http://sql-ex.ru/

Answer (score -2):

[rgrty.ru/sqltest](http://rgrty.ru/sqltest/main.aspx) Здесь вы можете в режиме online приобрести практические навыки и проверить свои знания **Firebird,MS SQL,Oracle**

Comment: Старайтесь давать развернутые ответы

Comment: @VyacheslavDanshin, сам вопрос подразумевает ответом ссылку. кмк, здесь более развёрнутый ответ особо не нужен.